# Installing libglib2.0-dev arm64 package on amd64 machine causes error

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install the libglib2.0-dev arm64 version on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 machine (for cross compilation purposes). I've already setup the repositories for both amd64 and arm64 following the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/1323570. However, when I run the command `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev:arm64`, I get the below errors. How can I fix this?

```bash
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-bin:arm64 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:arm64 (= 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libelf1:arm64 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev:arm64 : Depends: libffi-dev:arm64 (>= 3.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglib2.0-0:arm64 (= 2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libmount-dev:arm64 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libpcre3-dev:arm64 (>= 1:8.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libselinux1-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: zlib1g-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev-bin:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libglib2.0-0:arm64 (>= 2.39.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem here was that you were on Ubuntu 22.04 ("jammy") but the `sources.list` entries that you added from https://askubuntu.com/a/1323570 were intended for Ubuntu 20.04 ("focal") and the packages are incompatible between the two repos. You need to add the arm64 sources list entry for the matching Ubuntu version.